# How to change default directory for generating Java from XSD (JAXB)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a manve project, and I'm using the JAXB2 plugin to generate java class from XSD schema. By default, the classes are generated in the target folder, but I need to generate it in the src/main/java folder.

I tried adding the line attribute generateDirectory. The classes are generated where I want, but I can't import them on other places

Here is my  pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                <generateDirectory>src/main/java/com/evol/foo/generated-bar-sources</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And my java class using the generated files:

```
package com.evol.foo.service;
import com.evol.foo.generated-bar-sources; //error: cannot resolve symbol generated

@Component
public class XMLParserService {

  //ComplexType cannot be found
  public ComplexType parseErrorFile(String filePath) throws JAXBException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ComplexType.class);

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    ComplexType errFile = (ComplexType) 
    jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    return errFile;
  }
```

I'm using Intellij Comunity and Java 8.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the generated Java classes check the package declaration. I suspect it remained something default. Although I've never used jaxb maven plugin, but when I generated classes with command line tool, I had to specify both target directory and target package name.

Comment: Try to explicitly execute plugin goal before compile phase. E.g. `maven clean org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:generate compile`. Or try to bind plugin's goal to build phase `compile` by adding `<phase>compile</phase>` inside `<execution>` tag.

Comment: I tried both answers: added the generatePackage to the configuration and ran the plugin goal separately, and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the package should be declared outside the `generateDirectory` using `generatePackage` :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas</schemaDirectory>
        <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
        <generatePackage>com.evol.foo.generated-bar-sources</generatePackage>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```